# ubuntu terminal: grep for numbers compare

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, grep

I have text file with table `|ID | NAME | CREDIT|` and content

Is it real to get all lines, where `CREDIT < 1337`(for example) by `grep` and ONLY with GREP, no awk or something else?

Have no idea, tnx

Comment: Provide a sample i/p and verifiable expected o/p

Comment: You can't use `grep` for numerical comparison. Use `awk` for this. Like: `awk -F'|' '$4 < 1337'`

Comment: i/p:
`1 maria 1314
2 jake 200
3 bob 4000`
o/p:
`1 maria 1314
2 jake 200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with pure grep, but it's ugly. Here you are:

```
grep -e " .$" -e " ..$" -e " ...$" -e " 1[0-2]..$" -e " 13[0-2].$" -e " 133[0-6]$"
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is a job very much unsuited to `grep`. As an artisan, you should select your tools carefully, no-one wants to try cutting down a giant Karri tree with a screwdriver :-)

It *is* almost certainly a job for `awk`. You haven't specified your content lines so let's assume for now they're of the form:

```
|iii|nnnnnnn|ccccc|
```

where the `i`, `n` and `c` sequences are the relevant column data.

To get those lines where the credit value is less than 1337, it's a simple matter to do:

```
awk -F'|' '$4 < 1337 {print}' inputFileName
```

Comment: ye, I know how to do it with `awk`, but I have no argument to prove that I can't make it with `grep`, tnx

Comment: @T.Dmitry, do you have a system with `grep` but no `awk`. Because, otherwise, the question is rather ... err, less than useful. FWIW, `grep` is not really well suited for the task. It can certainly look for text and filter but it has no concept of *fields*, which appears to be what you're after. Nor is it easy to search for numeric values above some threshold.